# Two way binding in *ngFor on Array of elements(non-object)

Tags: arrays, angular, angular5

I have a simple array `tags = [];` and I'm pushing blank element on `addNew()` using `this.tags.push("");`. It creates blank element in that array.

Now, I'm using this array to add multiple items to be added from the input

```
<div class="row tagEntry" *ngFor="let tag of tags, let i = index">
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" name="tag-{{i}}" placeholder="Tag Name" [(ngModel)]="tag" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" (click)="removeTag(i)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

My TS file:

```
todoDesc: string = '';
  tags = [];

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addTag () {
    this.tags.push("");
    console.log(this.tags)
  }

  removeTag (index) {
    this.tags.splice(index, 1);
  }

  addTodo () {
    console.log(this.todoDesc, this.tags)
  }
```

Issue here is, it is not binding the input and array two way. When I log the array after updating inputs, the array displays items with all blank value.

[image: problem description]

How to two way bind the array of elements in Angular 5 using *ngFor?

Comment: You can use `FormArray` or even `QuerySelector` to do that. The second way is more easy to understand

Comment: And your TS part please ?

Comment: @selemmn, updated the question

Comment: @FaizanSaiyed That is actually correct. tags array is a blank value array. Can you provide a sample at stackblitz.

Comment: @FaizanSaiyed and your addTag button in HTML :)

Comment: @selemmn `<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-add" (click)="addTag()"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Add Tag</button>`

Comment: @Jai https://angular-vvf4ie.stackblitz.io   I want that array to be two way binded on my inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with Array whose changes are not being detected through reference. You can make the following changes -

### html

```
<div class="row tagEntry" *ngFor="let tag of tags; let i = index; trackBy:trackIndex">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Tag Name" [(ngModel)]="tags[i]" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" (click)="removeTag(i)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

### ts

Add the following function in ts file. This function is very important otherwise the array will re-build the complete UI on any change and you will loose the focus from the elememt.

```
trackIndex(index,item){
  return index;
}
```

Here is the working copy - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzdw6s